# Add function to button inside DataTables

Tags: function, codeigniter, datatables

How do I add a function to a button inside a DataTable with ID? I tried like this but it didn't work.

This is for the data:

```
{ data: 'kode_sertifikat',
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
      return row.dapat_sertifikat == 1 ? '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="sertifikat-button">' + data + '</button>' : '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning disabled" id="btn-sertifikat">' + data + '</button>';
    }
  },
```

And this is for the function :

```
$('#sertifikat-button').on('click', function () {
  const $modal = $('#form-modal');
  let selected = table.selectedRow();
  if(selected && dapatSertifikat(dataEvent, selected)) {
    window.open(`<?= base_url() ?>files/certificate/<?= $id_event ?>/${selected.id_mahasiswa}`, '_blank');
    // window.location.href = ;
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you researched various [questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+create+button+in+row+site:stackoverflow.com) (and all of their answers) which do something similar to what you need? There is also an excellent starting point in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) on the official DataTables web site.

Comment: Specific comments: (1) You can't use `data-id="sertifikat-button"` and then reference it with `$('#sertifikat-button')`. A `data-id` attribute is not the same as the `id` attribute (and also, you should avoid creating duplicate `id` values). (2) Look at how the official example in the DataTables web page uses a jQuery delegated event: `$('#example tbody').on('click', ...)`. The event is attached to a pre-existing HTML element, to ensure the event is registered, even if the table body is still being constructed.